# Increment a counter for only the first click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple buttons on a page, if a button is clicked I want it to count that button only on the first time.

In the below code snippet I have 3 buttons. If I click the buttons more than once it increments the counter multiple times, how do I only get the first click back. So based on below my counter should only rise up till 3 and nothing more

```js
var counter=0;
function count()
{
  $('.show').addClass("notification");
            $(".show").html(counter);
}
 $('.btn').on('click',function(){
      counter++
      count();
 })
```

```css
.notification {
    position: absolute;
    
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 8px;
    /*height: 9px;*/
    line-height: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
</div>
<span class="show">
```

Comment: should the buttons are clickable after the first click?

Comment: An alternative solution that you add disabled property to the button when it is clicked or add a custom class what you can check with hasClass or with :not(.customclass) pseudo-element selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with an arbitary class, say `clicked`. You can add this class on a single click to the `button` element and check this class each time when a button is clicked to detect whether or not this button is clicked previously.

```js
var counter = 0;
function count()
{
  $('.show').addClass("notification");
  $(".show").html(counter);
}
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
  var alreadyClicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
  if(!alreadyClicked){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    counter++;
    count();
  }
});
```

```css
.notification {
    position: absolute;
    
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 8px;
    /*height: 9px;*/
    line-height: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
</div>
<span class="show">
```

Comment: Glad to help you @John

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the click event binding inside the `click` callback.

In order to do this, you'll need to move the `click` callback function so that it is a function declaration (with a name), so that it can be referred to a second time for proper de-registration.

You can also add a simple CSS class to the, now (for all intents and purposes) disabled button for a visual clue to the user that the button is now disabled.

```js
var counter=0;
function count()
{
  $('.show').addClass("notification");
            $(".show").html(counter);
}
 $('.btn').on('click', increaseCount);
 
function increaseCount(){
      counter++
      count();
      // Job done, now disconnect this button from this event handler
      $(this).off("click", increaseCount);  
      $(this).addClass("disabled"); // For visual clue that button no longer works
 }
```

```css
.notification {
    position: absolute;
    
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 8px;
    /*height: 9px;*/
    line-height: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #b60000;
}

.disabled { pointer-events:none; opacity:.5; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
</div>
<span class="show">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) binding

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('.show').addClass("notification").html(counter);
}

$('.btn').one('click', function() {
  counter++
  count();
})
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  /*height: 9px;*/
  line-height: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class='btn'>Click</button>
  <button class='btn'>Click</button>
  <button class='btn'>Click</button>
</div>
<span class="show">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the event on button click

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
      counter++
      count();
      $(this).off('click');
});
```

Comment: `unbind` has been deprecated and should not be used (use `off` instead)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add a class to the clicked element, if you dont want to remove the event binding completely.

```js
let counter=0;
const count = () => {
  $('.show').addClass("notification");
  counter++;
  $(".show").html(counter);
}

$('.btn').on('click', (e) => {
  const $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  if(!$button.hasClass('clicked')){
    count();
    $button.addClass('clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
.notification {
    position: absolute;
    
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 8px;
    /*height: 9px;*/
    line-height: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
<button class='btn'>Click</button>
</div>
<span class="show">
```

Comment: `const $button = $(e.currentTarget);` isn't necessary. Just use `$(this)`

Comment: As @Pete pointed out. Arrow functions are anonymous and make our code more concise, and simplify function scoping and the `this` keyword.

Comment: @Pete I thought arrow functions simply did not affect `this` binding, not that they prevent it from being available.

Comment: @CristianS. I don't think that's what Pete said at all.

Comment: `this` doesnt get passed automatically. Thats the whole point of arrow functions. If you try doing $(this) you will get the browser window :D

Comment: @Pete I think you should differentiate es6 from arrow functions. It's arrow functions that are the culprit, not es6 as a whole.

Comment: @CristianS. Yes, but that is not the same thing as what your first comment or what Pete said.